# Can ILE RPG program variable values remain in memory between calls?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

If I create an ILE RPG program with DFTACTGRP(*NO), my understanding is the program remains in memory until the activation group is destroyed. If I exit the program with LR switched off, do variables get reinitialized on the next call or do they hold their values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short Answer**
No, they do not get reinitialized, unless `ACTGRP(*New)` is set or you reclaim the activation group in some other way.

**Long Answer**
`*INLR` is a function of the RPG cycle, not of Activation groups, and should function mostly as expected (except the program is not unloaded), as long as you are using a cycle main program. For linear main programs, all bets are off. The manual says that features dependent on the cycle "may not be specified" in linear modules. The documentation does not specifically indicate directly that `*INLR` will not function as expected in a linear module, but, you need to know that `*INLR` is tied to the cycle, and that linear modules do not include the cycle. A linear module is one that uses the `MAIN` or `NOMAIN` keyword. Incidently, there are other things that control variable initialization as well as (or instead of) `LR`.

If you use `ACTGRP(*NEW)`, a new activation group is created when the program starts, and implicitly ended when the program ends. So the program is closed down every time whether `LR` is on or off, or even whether the program is a cycle main program, or a linear main program.

If you use a named activation group, or `ACTGRP(*CALLER)` and the caller is running in a named activation group, and manually reclaim the activation group when all programs in the activation group are ended, then fields will be initialized. `RCLRSC` has no affect here.

If you use the default activation group, or `ACTGRP(*CALLER)` and the caller is running in the default activation group, and manually `RCLRSC`, then fields will be initialized. `RCLACTGRP` has no affect here. Be careful, this can cause issues.

And finally, This all applies only to variables in the global scope. Local scope variables, those defined within a sub-procedure, are always initialized on entry, and released on return, unless they are defined as static. Static local variables behave like global variables. That is, they are allocated and initialized during the first call of the procedure, and persist across calls.

Comment: Thank you @jmarkmurphy for a detailed answer. What happens if I initialize the variable with an inz declaration. Will it be set to this value every time the program is called or just the first time it's loaded into memory. I.e. will an inz declaration overwrite the value from the last call or will the value from a previous call be retained?

Comment: Same answer. `Inz` just determines what a variable is initialized to when the program starts if it is initialized.

Comment: Your answer is what I would have expected from reading about activation groups. However, when de-bugging, I call it from a test harness repeatedly and every time the program runs it re-initializes the variable. The program runs in a named activation group. The code is in a module and is compiled at target release V7R1M0. I'm not sure what I can do to find out what is re-initializing the variable.

Comment: Where is the variable declared? In the global scope, or within a sub-procedure? Read the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: The program entry procedure is the first module, which is where the variable is declared and used. The variable is global.

Comment: Now which module, where in the module? Is the variable declared between  `dcl-proc` - `end-proc` statements, or is it declared at the top of the module with the other global d-specs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136880/discussion-between-jmarkmurphy-and-mike).

Comment: It is declared  with a d spec: d w_variable    s              1a   inz('Y')

Comment: Chat please, see link above

Comment: Discussion established that LR was left on causing the variable to re-initialize.

Answer (score 3):

Linear-main modules behave like nomain modules regarding global variables. Global variables are initialized the first time a procedure gets called in the module and they never get reinitialized. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/cycvslinear.htm

Comment: Thank you for contributing to our discussion, this is the first time i had come across the term 'linear-main module' and am interested to study the link you provided.